# program to check unread mails every 30 minutes and trigger code for each unread mail in python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, jira-rest-api

I have to trigger Jira ticket creation code when new mail comes.
My Jira ticket creation code is ready. Now i have to check mail box every 30 minutes and trigger the unread mails as input for jira ticket creation code.

Comment: you can use the imaplib library to read emails. then read only unread emails every 30 minutes and call this jira ticket creation code if you found unread emails.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/creating-issues-and-comments-from-email-779288896.html Jira can already do that.